# Vb.net How to Make the Timer countdown restart at 30 seconds when clicked on a new button in the same form

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to do a project and i'm still learning and this timer thing is something very new to me.

*You are required to build a board game. The game should be played on a 4 x 4 grid in pairs. Each grid cell contains a hidden question which the pair needs to answer.

1. The players take turns in playing the game. Each player generates two random numbers and place the cell on the grid indicated by the numbers. Once clicked, the question for the clicked grid cell is displayed. For example if the generated number is a 2 and a 3 the player clicks in the 2 x 3 grid cell to view the hidden question. You may use any kind of questions.
2. A player should only be able to click and view the question hidden beneath the grid cell represented by the random numbers.
3. At the start of the game, the initial score for each player should have a value of 0. For each question answered, the score increases by 5. You can display the score anywhere within the interface.
4. Each player should be given a duration of 30 seconds to answer a question. This value should be displayed on the user interface. The value should decrease with time and this decrement should be visible on screen at any point in time. Once the value reaches 0 the other player should be given the chance to answer the question. If both the players fail in answering a question, the question should be marked as unanswered. You can display the time left anywhere within the user interface.
5. The game should end when all the questions have been attempted by the players. When the game ends, the winner should be announced. The winner should be the one with the highest score.
6. Once the game is over, the questions and answers along with the players should be displayed.*

[This is what its supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4EHu.jpg)

This is what mine looks [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVM0R.jpg)

Now [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcGev.jpg) is working just fine when i click on the 1st button even when they get the answer wrong or they go over time the timers will reset and countdown from 30 but when i click on the 2nd button the timer doesn't work even when i attached a second timer.

here is the code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private TargetDT As DateTime
    Private TargetDT1 As DateTime
    Public CountDownFrom As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(33)
    Public CountDownFrom1 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(33)
    Private TargetDTQ2 As DateTime
    Private TargetDTQ2a As DateTime
    Public CountDownFromQ2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(33)
    Public CountDownFromQ2a As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(33)


    Private Sub frmSinglePlayer_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Interval = 500
        TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)
        TargetDT1 = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom1)
        TargetDTQ2 = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFromQ2)
        TargetDTQ2a = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFromQ2a)

    End Sub

    Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        Dim ts1 As TimeSpan = TargetDT1.Subtract(DateTime.Now)

        If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
            lblTime1.Text = ts.ToString("ss")

        Else
            lblTime1.Text = ":00"
            Timer1.Stop()
            MessageBox.Show("Out of Time!! Now player 2 can answer")

            lblTime1.Text = ts1.ToString("ss")
            Q1.TextBox1.Hide()
            Q1.Button1.Hide()
            Q1.TextBox2.Show()
            Q1.Button2.Show()

        End If

    End Sub
    Public Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Dim ts2 As TimeSpan = TargetDTQ2.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        Dim ts3 As TimeSpan = TargetDTQ2a.Subtract(DateTime.Now)

        If ts2.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
            lblTime1.Text = ts2.ToString("ss")

        Else
            lblTime1.Text = ":00"
            Timer2.Stop()
            MessageBox.Show("Out of Time!! Now player 2 can answer")

            lblTime1.Text = ts3.ToString("ss")
            Q1.TextBox1.Hide()
            Q1.Button1.Hide()
            Q1.TextBox2.Show()
            Q1.Button2.Show()

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click

        Q1.Show()
        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
        Q2.Show()
        Timer2.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
        Application.Restart()

    End Sub

End Class
```

This is my code for the second Button

```
Public Class Q2

    Private TargetDT As DateTime
    Public CountDownFrom As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(36)

    Private Sub frmSinglePlayer_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer3.Interval = 500
        TargetDT = DateTime.Now.Add(CountDownFrom)

    End Sub

    Public Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)

        If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
            Form1.lblTime2.Text = ts.ToString("ss")

        Else
            'lblTime1.Text = ":00"
            Timer3.Stop()
            'MessageBox.Show("Out of Time!! Now player 2 can answer")
            'Form1.lblTime1.Text = ts.ToString("ss")
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Correctanswer As String
        Correctanswer = ("Venus")
        Dim result As Integer
        result = String.Compare(TextBox1.Text, Correctanswer, True)
        Dim result2 = String.Compare(TextBox2.Text, Correctanswer, True)

        If result = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Bingo!")
            Form1.txtP1.Text = Val(Form1.txtP1.Text) + 1
            Form1.lblTime1.Text = ":00"
            Form1.lblTime1.Hide()
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf result < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong!")
            TextBox1.Text = " "
            Form1.lblTime1.Text = ":00"
            Form1.lblTime1.Hide()
            Form1.lblTime2.Show()
            Timer3.Start()
            TextBox1.Hide()
            TextBox2.Show()
            Button1.Hide()
            Button2.Show()
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim Correctanswer As String
        Correctanswer = ("Venus")
        Dim result As Integer
        result = String.Compare(TextBox1.Text, Correctanswer, True)
        Dim result2 = String.Compare(TextBox2.Text, Correctanswer, True)

        If result2 = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Bingo!")
            Form1.txtP2.Text = Val(Form1.txtP2.Text) + 1
            Form1.lblTime2.Text = ":00"
            Form1.lblTime2.Hide()
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf result < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong!")
            TextBox1.Text = " "
            Form1.lblTime1.Text = ":00"
            Form1.lblTime1.Hide()
            Form1.lblTime2.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

PS. Also if someone can help explain how to change a buttons color from the code and not on click (This is so that the palyers can see what grid they have already clicked on)

Comment: You really don't want a separate form for each question. Just put a label on a form and changed the text of the label to the selected question. Have you learned about classes yet?

Comment: What happens if the random numbers select the same square more than once?

Comment: @Mary ohh didn't think about putting it all into 1 form hmm so like I should reference the buttons from the main form to signal which label its supposed to have on nice.  I'm just a beginner and i haven't learnt much more than the basic if statements, For/Do loops and a little abit about connecting to database.

All that aside do you know how to reset the countdown button for some reason it just keep playing from when i last stop it like if i stopped it at 23 it will continue there again. I kept trying to mess around with the TimeSpan and the Date.Time.Now.Add but it always didn't 100% work